# Three column responsive equal height, with border. How to make it in CSS?

Tags: css, equals

How do I make multiple columns with equal heights that has a border between each section AND keeping it responsive... (see image below). I know you can use a background image if you have **two** columns but when theres more, the whole responsive part goes going.

EDIT: heres a jsfiddle I've made: http://jsfiddle.net/kF9LA/

[image: mockup of the desired layout]

Comment: Generally you should try a few things first and show what you've done before asking the question, rather than asking the community to build a layout from scratch for you...

Comment: Ok, i'll have an example that i've made coming up in a few secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about two bg images, one with a border 1/3 from the left, and one with a border 1/3 right from the right? Then apply them in a pair of containers with `background-position:33.3% 0;` and `background-position:66.6% 0;`, respectively.

Similar to using a single image with a border in the middle, and `background-position:50% 0;`

**Edit:**

After running a [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/sD8Fe/7/) this seems to work, and it's fluid/responsive.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bg1">
        <div class="bg2">
            <div class="content">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width:100%; border:2px solid #000;}

/* Tile a 2x1 image for the border */
.bg1 {background:url(img/border.png) repeat-y 33.3% 0;}
.bg2 {background:url(img/border.png) repeat-y 66.6% 0;}
```

**Edit 2:**

Removed `height:200px;` from .content and added some text content to the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/sD8Fe/7/), to show that the height can grow based on the content. Replaced the two bg images with a single 2x1 image.

Comment: Shame I need the height to be dynamic to the content, otherwise this solution would be the best!

Comment: It should work dynamically. I hard-coded `height:200px` because I don't have any content in my example. But if you remove that and add some content (and some inner columns for the content), it should work dynamically. The bg images I created happen to be 200px in height, but they could be 1px as well, since they're tiled.

Comment: Also, just realized the same image can be used for both bg containers. And if not for IE8 and earlier, you could specify multiple bg images in a single `background` property, and use a single bg container instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the solution from Matthew James Taylor: 
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: Yes I've seen it, neat solution. However his example doesn't allow me to have border like I've shown in the image

Comment: Looks like this would work in a Responsive Design (since it doesn't use any px values). But is it well-suited for displaying borders (with consistent thickness) rather than filling in the bg?

Comment: You can add the border to the right of your background. Not the most elegant solution, but it works pretty well on some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a couple of answers in a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905779/1284654). The best way to do this depends entirely on if you need the user to *visually* see the divs are the same height. If your final site will look like this mock-up (the only visual cue being the borders), you don't necessarily need to use MJT's method and instead could use a background image, like [this](http://kristinachilds.com/example/testes2.html).

As stated in the comment in the link above, this method won't work for horizontally fluid layouts, but if you have a fixed-width layout, you can use the background image for as many columns as you like. Just make sure you're math is right :)

However if your layout needs to be completely fluid, MJT's method is best. It requires extra mark-up, but is bulletproof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is essential that the content is responsive/fluid.

Comment: ACK! i can't comment on other answers yet. @sebasiongraz, it will absolutely allow you to make borders! just style the columns to have borders on them. you could even do it by setting a background color and setting a margin of 1px on the columns so the background shows through, making it *look* like borders when it is really just a background "mask"

Comment: click on the link, yo! [here it is again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10905779/1284654) and here is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6yZxw/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is just to use a table with bordered cells, but if you have a lot of time on your hands, the CSS approach suggested by @nebulousGirl is the way.