# Applying a clearfix to nth-child without additional markup

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage, css-selectors, clearfix

First up, for extreme clarity, here a JS fiddle demonstrating what I'm trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/bb_matt/VsH7X/

Here's the explanation - my rationale:

I'm creating a responsive site using the 1140 grid framework.
It's a fairly complex layout.

I've created a re-usable simple gallery class which can drop into any defined column size & using media queries, I apply relevant percentage widths to the li elements.
Each of the li elements has a right margin of 5%.
I'm using nth-child(xn+x) in the media queries to remove the right margin at the end of each row.

Everything works well - images resize as the layout resizes, the number of gallery items in a row work as I've defined based on percentages.

The only remaining issue to fix is to clear between rows. 
I can't add additional html markup and I want to steer clear of overly complex jquery fixes.

I know of two ways to fix this, but I'm not keen on either of them.

First fix, simply using display: inline-block on the li elements, with a vertical align of top, would flow everything correctly... *however*, all the percentages get shot and the gallery items no longer neatly fit in the allocated space.

Second fix, give the list items a height. This is the route I will go down if necessary - it will require a different height depending on the resolution - no big deal, but not as neat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VsH7X/5/

I added a `clear: left` to the first item in each new row.

```
ul.gallery li:nth-child(5n+6) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Keep in mind that the `:nth-child` pseudo class does not work in IE6-8, or FF3 and under.
​

Comment: You don't need about half of the properties there in your `:after` rule which cater to the older browsers that don't support `:nth-child()`. Namely, `content` can be an empty string, and you don't need `height: 0` or `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: You're right. I also just realized that you don't even need the `:after` clearfix at all, since the first element of each new row having `clear: left` effectively handles that for us. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/VsH7X/4/

Comment: Made one more update: realized it should be `:nth-child(5n+6)`. This was apparent when I added more rows to the markup: http://jsfiddle.net/VsH7X/5/

Comment: Nice one! - the (5n+6) is where I was going wrong. I did try (6n + 6), amongst a few other random dabblings.